# WIth Angular's ui-router, is it possible to get a list of all registered states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im architecting a fairly large angular application using ui-router. Im trying to add whitelisted states, which in this case means states that dont require authentication before you can see them. Id like to be able to specify entire states and their substates as whitelisted - that is, if I have states such as:

```
index.home
index.library
index.messages
index.messages.inbox
index.messages.outbox
index.messages.outbox.starred
```

Id like to be able to set 'index.messages.*', and not block any state that starts with 'index.messages'. I managed to do this by adding a listener for `'$stateChangeStart'` and doing some fancy string parsing on 'toState.name', but I suspect this would be easier to do if I had a full list of available states. Is there any way to get that? A cursory poke through the source showed me a *$stateProvider.states* object, but there doenst seem to be any way to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that you are searching for method **`$state.get()`**, check it here:

#### [API Reference `$state`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> **`get(stateOrName, context)`**
>
> Returns the state configuration object for any specific state or all states.
>   Parameters
>
> - stateOrName (optional)   stringobject
>     (absolute or relative) If provided, will only get the config for the requested state. **If not provided, returns an array of ALL state configs.**
> - context (optional) stringobject
>     When stateOrName is a relative state reference, the state will be retrieved relative to context.

As stated in doc: **"...If not provided, returns an array of ALL state configs..."**